# Word for special/fancy/unusual/awesome recipes

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Hey i am searching for a word, which fits the meaning i want to spread. It is about recipes that are unusual and fancy.. So they are more sophisticated and more awesome than other recipes.

I am from germany and not sure which word fits the best..

Something like Fancy Recipes, does that work or is it uncommon?

thanks a lot

Comment: Why not use "sophisticated"? If not **elaborate** is quite fitting for a sophisticated and fancy recipe.

Comment: Gourmet perhaps?

Comment: sophisticated would work, but i don't want it to sound too difficult but more tasty and special.. Gourmet would be an option :)

Comment: There's 'Fabulous Recipes' but that gets used *a lot*.

Comment: You mean recipes like this? 

http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Extraordinary-Cookbook-Friends-Forget/dp/1856269213/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1395144287&sr=8-1&keywords=extraordinary%20cookbook

Comment: I feel like the use of "gourmet" is incredibly saturated, almost as bad as slapping "professional" on tools.

Comment: I think specificity is the key to this answer, so we need more detail. HOW are they more sophisticated? WHAT makes them more awesome?

Comment: Yes kinda like this. But not really weird recipes :D they are just very good

Comment: It is about fitness recipes.. Normally a lot of fitness recipes just suck and don't taste that great. These recipes are kinda new and tasty really good eventhough they are very healthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use a word like `gastronomy` you'll find stuff that definitely matches your criteria...but maybe too specific

unusual & fancy for sure though

Comment: Gastronomy (or rather gastronomic for an adjective) does not necessarily imply fancy and/or sophisticated or unusual. Gastronomy is just "the study of food", it sometimes focuses on "gourmet" cuisine. I suspect "gourmet" was the word you were looking for, not gastronomy.

Comment: Yeah...but have a try searching gastronomy + recipes - most of the recipes that use gastronomy in their description have to do with "molecular gastronomy" (or are copycats that think molecular gastronomy is super fancy and appealing - and want their recipes to stand out in the same way)

Answer (score 1):

When describing food, something special, exotic, unique, and wonderful is *gourmet*.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if done at a restaurant or at home they are considered **family recipes**.